How can I move files from the Windows partition to the WSL one?
I installed Ubuntu through WSL is the Windows virtualisation tool. And I want to move (copy) some files from the memory partition is controlled by Windows to the partition is controlled by Ubuntu. I tried to do it through Bash using the
sudo cp <lc_disk>:\\<dir_with_files>\\<file.txt> \\wsl.localhost\\Ubuntu\\home\\<username_for_Ubuntu>\\<target_dir>

command. But the error is raised after running it:
cp: cannot stat <lc_disk>:\\<dir_with_files>\\<file.txt>: No such file or directory.

I tried to replace \\ with / but it didn't help: there is the same error.
I tried to copy files via cmd using the copy command:
copy "<lc_disk>:\<dir_with_files>\<file.txt>" "\\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu\home\burks_tedold_ubuntu\Test"

but there is the error:
Copy-Item: Access to the path '\\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu\home\<username_for_Ubuntu>\<target_dir>\<file.txt>' is denied.

So, how can I copy my files?

SysInfo
WSL
WSL version: 2.1.5.0
Kernel version: 5.15.146.1-2
WSLg version: 1.0.60
MSRDC version: 1.2.5105
Direct3D version: 1.611.1-81528511
DXCore version: 10.0.25131.1002-220531-1700.rs-onecore-base2-hyp
Windows version: 10.0.22631.3374
Ubuntu
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Release: 22.04
Codename: jammy

if you are running the copy command (cp) from bash in WSL the C drive can be accessed as /mnt/c
so for example the C:\Users folder can be accessed as
/mnt/c/Users/

Another example: if you need to move this windows folder (and all its subfolders)
C:\temp\foo
into the home of your WSL user, you can launch this command:
mv -R /mnt/c/temp/foo ~/

(you may or may not need to prepend sudo depending on the source folder permissions - most of the times the directory c:\temp is readable and writable by all local users)
